# How to erase the internal plot and close the gap between the plot in facet_wrap?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to ask about how to hide the ticks and axis of y-axis in the second and the third plot of facet_wrap.
Here is my code.

```
library("ggplot2")
library("readr")
library("dplyr")
library(tidyr)
library(magrittr)
library(ggprism)
library(stringr)

plan$passage <- c(1, 1, 3, 3, 1, 1, 3, 3, 1, 1, 3, 3)
plan$value <- c(0.7858260,0.4605525,0.7958260,0.5505525,4.5000000 0.3223315 4.1000000 3.2700000 4.6000000)
plan$sd <-  c(0.7858260,0.4605525,0.7958260,0.5505525,4.5000000,0.3223315,4.1000000,3.2700000,4.6000000, 0.3523315,5.6000000,4.4200000)
newPlanEc$gravity <- c("uni", "iso","uni", "iso","uni", "iso","uni", "iso","uni", "iso","uni", "iso",)
newPlanEc$parameter <- c("conc.e", "conc.e", "conc.e", "conc.e","conc.m","conc.m","conc.m","conc.m","conc.l","conc.l","conc.l","conc.l")


no_grid <- theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank())
tick <- annotation_ticks(sides = "bl", outside = FALSE, minor.length = unit(0, "pt"), tick.length = unit(0, "pt"))
no_ribbon <- theme(strip.background = element_blank(),
                   strip.text.x = element_blank(), strip.text.y = element_blank())
no_ribbonBGX <- theme(strip.background = element_blank(), strip.placement = "outside")

facetConnected <- theme(panel.spacing = unit(-8, "pt"))

titleSpacing <- theme(axis.title.x = element_text(vjust= -1),
                      axis.text.x = element_text(vjust=-0.5), axis.title.y = element_text(vjust= 3))

p1 <- ggplot(plan, aes(x = passage, y = value, fill = factor(gravity, levels = c("uni", "iso")) )) + 
  geom_bar(stat = 'identity', position = position_dodge(width = 1.2),width = 1, color = "black")  +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = value - sd, ymax = value + sd), position = position_dodge(width = 1.2), width = 1) +
  facet_wrap(vars(factor(parameter, levels = c("conc.e", "conc.m", "conc.l"))), ncol = 3, scales = "free_y",  labeller = as_labeller(facetLabel),strip.position="bottom")  +
  scale_y_continuous(limit = c(0,7.5), expand = expansion(mult = c(0,0.03))) + 
  scale_x_continuous(limit = c(0, 4), breaks = c(1,3), labels = c("Low", "High")) +
  xlab("Passage") + ylab31  + coord_cartesian(clip = "off") + tick +
  FillScale + theme_bw() + no_grid + theme(aspect.ratio = 2) + facetConnected + titleSpacing + no_ribbonBGX +theme(strip.text.y = element_blank())

p1
```

I have tried using the panel.spacing but it is no work.
Thank you

Comment: Welcome to SO! As a first time contributor you did well in trying to provide a reproducible example. However, you should always check that the example code is working which is not the case (When you run in a fresh R session you will get a bunch of errors).  Second, it's easier to help you if you provide a minimal example code which focuses on the issue. Approx 50% of your code deals with theming. Third, provide only the necessary packages, i.e. ggplot2 and ggprism.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure about why all theming is necessary but to get rid of the axes for the inner panels and the gap you could drop `scales="free_y"` from `facet_wrap` which in your code will have no effect as you fixed the `limits` in `scale_y_continuous`:

```
library(ggplot2)

plan$parameter <- factor(plan$parameter, levels = c("conc.e", "conc.m", "conc.l"))
plan$gravity <- factor(plan$gravity, levels = c("uni", "iso"))

ggplot(plan, aes(x = passage, y = value, fill = gravity)) +
  geom_col(position = position_dodge(width = 1.2), width = 1, color = "black") +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = value - sd, ymax = value + sd),
    position = position_dodge(width = 1.2), width = 1
  ) +
  facet_wrap(~parameter,
    ncol = 3,
    # labeller = as_labeller(facetLabel),
    strip.position = "bottom"
  ) +
  scale_y_continuous(
    limits = c(0, 7.5),
    expand = expansion(mult = c(0, 0.03))
  ) +
  scale_x_continuous(
    limits = c(0, 4),
    breaks = c(1, 3),
    labels = c("Low", "High")
  ) +
  xlab("Passage") +
  # ylab31 +
  coord_cartesian(clip = "off") +
  # tick +
  # FillScale +
  theme_bw() +
  no_grid +
  theme(aspect.ratio = 2) +
  facetConnected +
  titleSpacing +
  no_ribbonBGX +
  theme(strip.text.y = element_blank())
```

[image]

**DATA**

```
plan <- data.frame(
  passage = c(1, 1, 3, 3, 1, 1, 3, 3, 1, 1, 3, 3),
  value = c(
    0.7858260, 0.4605525, 0.7958260, 0.5505525, 4.5000000, 0.3223315,
    4.1000000, 3.2700000, 4.6000000, 0.3523315, 5.6000000, 4.4200000
  ),
  sd = c(
    0.7858260, 0.4605525, 0.7958260, 0.5505525, 4.5000000, 0.3223315,
    4.1000000, 3.2700000, 4.6000000, 0.3523315, 5.6000000, 4.4200000
  ),
  gravity = c(
    "uni", "iso", "uni", "iso", "uni", "iso",
    "uni", "iso", "uni", "iso", "uni", "iso"
  ),
  parameter = c(
    "conc.e", "conc.e", "conc.e", "conc.e", "conc.m", "conc.m",
    "conc.m", "conc.m", "conc.l", "conc.l", "conc.l", "conc.l"
  )
)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. It's works actually. For the theme(), I used for merging those plot together and put the ribbon label to the bottom side of the plot